# Bridge private & public network to guest in KVM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, dhcp, bridge

I have a CentOS 7 box running KVM with all the usuals installed (bridge-utils etc).

I have created a bridge which should in theory connect the guest to our private office network (192.168.99.X). The host is using DHCP rather than a static IP address, I'm not sure if that could be the issue or if it's just me not knowing what I'm doing.

The NIC is currently set up as follows:

`ifcfg-enp30s0`

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp30s0"
UUID="25962652-d1df-469b-885b-376a0604f333"
DEVICE="enp30s0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
BRIDGE=bridge0
ONBOOT="yes"
```

And the bride is `ifcfg-bridge0`

```
DEVICE="bridge0"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
DEFROUTE=yes
```

From what I can tell this should work. I don't want to use `virbr0` as it will assign something in the .122 range, we need to be able to access VMs via SSH without tunnelling through the host machine.

Any help is much appreciated!